# Does List in Scala is not homogeneous collection?

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming

I have this following function which set the head of list with new value

```
  def setHead[A](ls: List[A], ele: A):List[A] = {
    ls match {
    case Nil => ls
    case x :: xs => ele :: xs
    }
  }
```

and output of this after calling it with

```
println(setHead(List(-1,-2,-3,4,5,6), (x :Int)  =>  x < 0))
```

is

```
List(<function1>, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6)
```

But the function takes a type 'A' argument and I am passing a list with type 'Int' and a function then how does it compile and run because type 'A' cant be Int and  at the same time.

Comment: Just to add to the answers: You might be puzzled that the compiler lets you write such apparently wrong code. But everything is fine. If you were to further use the returned value, like `setHead(1 :: 2 :: Nil, 2).sum == 4`, then the compiler would complain, because you cannot `.sum`  a `List[Any]`. So your apparent mistake (calling `setHead` with some strange `elem`) would manifest in an compile error "later in your code".

Comment: But `A` can be `Any`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `Int` and `Int => Boolean` inherit from `Any`, which is the root of the Scala class hierarchy:

- `Int` inherits from `AnyVal`, which inherits from `Any`.
- `Int => Boolean` inherits from `AnyRef`, which inherits from `Any`.

And we can check the type of an expression in the Scala REPL in a couple of ways:

```
scala>  def setHead[A](ls: List[A], ele: A):List[A] = ls match {
     |    case Nil => ls
     |    case x :: xs => ele :: xs
     |  }
setHead: [A](ls: List[A], ele: A)List[A]

scala> setHead(List(-1,-2,-3,4,5,6), (x :Int)  =>  x < 0)
res0: List[Any] = List($$Lambda$1256/1374785073@3290b1a6, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> :type setHead(List(-1,-2,-3,4,5,6), (x :Int)  =>  x < 0)
List[Any]
```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `setHead()` the way you did, the compiler will conclude `A` as `Any` which is the lowest common ancestor of `Int` and `Int => Boolean`:

```
setHead(List(-1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6), (x :Int) => x < 0)
// res1: List[Any] = List(<function1>, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6)
```

The compiler would've complained, had you made `A` explicit:

```
setHead[Int](List(-1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6), (x :Int) => x < 0)
// <console>:16: error: type mismatch;
// found   : Int => Boolean
// required: Int
```